# Generative book cover

Tags: tikz-pgf, metapost, bookcover

I wonder if it is possible to use LaTeX tools to generate a book cover inspired by Faber Finds project.

http://blog.fabric.ch/index.php?/archives/62-Faber-Finds-generative-book-covers.html

The ornaments on the frames are amazing!

Comment: Since most of the ornaments can be generated with loops, designing them with `metapost`, `tikz` or `pstricks` looks doable to me.

Comment: As there is really only one unique section of the frame (from the right angle to the center of any given side) which is reflected and/or rotated 7 times, this seems like an ideal use for a (probably rather complex) Ti*k*Z `pic`. Thinking...

Comment: On closer inspection, while it would be possible to reflect/rotate one segment seven time, this appears to be on entire corner repeated three times. Still, looks like a job for a `pic` and some careful use of `rnd`. Still thinking...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A first, quite sketchy attempt using MetaPost. It's not as sophisticated for we use fewer parameters and our frame is actually squared, but proposals are fine IMHO. Just notice that because results are in fact random, they could look a bit chaotic.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[shellescape,latex]{gmp}
\newcommand{\lowbudgetart}[4]{%
\begin{mpost}[name=lowbudgetart]
vardef LowBudgetArt(expr Iter, Unit, Chaos) =
    save Primordia; path Primordia[]; 
    %We can add more paths 
    Primordia[1] := 
        origin .. (0,1) .. (1,0) .. (2,1) .. (3,1) 
        .. (3,0) .. (2.25,0) .. (2.25,0.5);
    Primordia[2] := 
        origin .. (0,2) .. (1,2.25) .. (2.5,0.25) .. (2.5,1);
    Primordia[3] :=
        origin .. (1,-1) .. (2,-1) .. (2.5, -0.5) .. (2,0);
    Primordia[4] := 
        origin .. controls (1.4,-0.5) and (1.99,0) .. (2,2);
    Primordia[5] := origin .. (3,0) .. (3,1) .. (2.9,1) 
        .. (2.9,-0.2) .. (1,-0.5) .. (0.2,-1);
    for i = 1 upto 5:
        Primordia[i] := (Primordia[i] shifted -center Primordia[i]) scaled (Unit*uniformdeviate(1+Chaos));
    endfor;
    save Result; picture Result;
    Result := image(
    for g = 1 upto Iter:
    for i = 1 upto 5:
        draw image(
        draw Primordia[i];
        %I like squared tips. Remove if unwanted.
        if uniformdeviate(1)<0.5:
        drawdot (point 0 of Primordia[i]) withpen pensquare
            scaled 5;
        fi
        if uniformdeviate(1)>0.5:
        drawdot (point infinity of Primordia[i]) withpen currentpen
            scaled 10;
        fi
        )
        rotated (uniformdeviate(1)*360)
        shifted 
        if uniformdeviate(1) < 0.5:
            (6Unit*(up+right*(uniformdeviate(1))))
        else:
            (6Unit*(right+up*(uniformdeviate(1))))
        fi
        ;
    endfor
    endfor
    );
    draw Result ;
    draw Result reflectedabout(up,down);
    draw Result reflectedabout(left,right);
    draw (Result reflectedabout(up,down)) 
        reflectedabout (left,right);
enddef;
drawoptions(withcolor (0,0,0.5));
LowBudgetArt(#1, \mpdim{#2}, #3);
drawoptions();
label(\btex #4 etex, origin);
\end{mpost}%
\usempost{lowbudgetart}%
}
\begin{document}
%#1=no of iterations
%#2=unit size
%#3=randomization (from zero to one)
%#4=text
\lowbudgetart{6}{5mm}{0.1}{\Large\textbf{Con\TeX t rules}}%
\lowbudgetart{8}{8mm}{0.1}{\Huge\textbf{Ducks in S. Korea}}%
\lowbudgetart{9}{1cm}{0.1}{\Huge\textbf{Peruvian cajón}}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]